# Library for android for Google cardboard barrel distortion

Tags: android, image-processing, google-cardboard, distortion

I am trying to implement a 3D app for Android that should also support cardboard like viewers. I have seen some of those images and they seem to have some kind of barrel distortion in order to be orthogonal through the cardboard lenses.

So I was looking for algorithms or libraries specifically for Java/Android that would help me achieving this.

I have found this implementation: http://www.helviojunior.com.br/fotografia/barrel-and-pincushion-distortion/

It would be great to have something like this because it has everything I'd need. Unfortunately it's for C# and it has some specific code that I just couldn't easily translate into more generic code.

Then there is a simpler Java  implementation here: http://popscan.blogspot.de/2012/04/fisheye-lens-equation-simple-fisheye.html

I have changed it to:

```
public static Bitmap fisheye(Bitmap srcimage) {
/*
 *    Fish eye effect
 *    tejopa, 2012-04-29
 *    http://popscan.blogspot.com
 *    http://www.eemeli.de
 */

    // get image pixels
    double w = srcimage.getWidth();
    double h = srcimage.getHeight();
    int[] srcpixels = new int[(int)(w*h)];
    srcimage.getPixels(srcpixels, 0, (int)w, 0, 0, (int)w, (int)h);

    Bitmap resultimage = srcimage.copy(srcimage.getConfig(), true);

    // create the result data
    int[] dstpixels = new int[(int)(w*h)];
    // for each row
    for (int y=0;y<h;y++) {
        // normalize y coordinate to -1 ... 1
        double ny = ((2*y)/h)-1;
        // pre calculate ny*ny
        double ny2 = ny*ny;
        // for each column
        for (int x=0;x<w;x++) {
            // preset to black
            dstpixels[(int)(y*w+x)] = 0;

            // normalize x coordinate to -1 ... 1
            double nx = ((2*x)/w)-1;
            // pre calculate nx*nx
            double nx2 = nx*nx;
            // calculate distance from center (0,0)
            // this will include circle or ellipse shape portion
            // of the image, depending on image dimensions
            // you can experiment with images with different dimensions
            double r = Math.sqrt(nx2+ny2);
            // discard pixels outside from circle!
            if (0.0<=r&&r<=1.0) {
                double nr = Math.sqrt(1.0-r*r);
                // new distance is between 0 ... 1
                nr = (r + (1.0-nr)) / 2.0;
                // discard radius greater than 1.0
                if (nr<=1.0) {
                    // calculate the angle for polar coordinates
                    double theta = Math.atan2(ny,nx);
                    // calculate new x position with new distance in same angle
                    double nxn = nr*Math.cos(theta);
                    // calculate new y position with new distance in same angle
                    double nyn = nr*Math.sin(theta);
                    // map from -1 ... 1 to image coordinates
                    int x2 = (int)(((nxn+1)*w)/2.0);
                    // map from -1 ... 1 to image coordinates
                    int y2 = (int)(((nyn+1)*h)/2.0);
                    // find (x2,y2) position from source pixels

                    int srcpos = (int)(y2*w+x2);
                    // make sure that position stays within arrays
                    if (srcpos>=0 & srcpos < w*h) {
                        // get new pixel (x2,y2) and put it to target array at (x,y)
                        dstpixels[(int)(y*w+x)] = srcpixels[srcpos];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    resultimage.setPixels(dstpixels, 0, (int)w, 0, 0, (int)w, (int)h);
    //return result pixels
    return resultimage;
}
```

But it doesn't have this lens `factor`, so the resulting image is always a full circle/ellipse.

Any chance you could point me to some working Java code or library or (maybe even better) help me to amend this code for the lens factor to be taken into account (0.0 <= factor <= 1.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work.

Bottom line: I created a Bitmap bigger than the original Bitmap, and then I drew the original Bitmap on the new Bitmap (and centered it there) using

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, null, new Rect(x, y, r, b), null);
```

I used the Java algorithm posted in my question to create the effect on the new Bitmap. That worked great.